# Using SQL to retrieve records within a period

Tags: sql, date, db2

I have a column called `DUEDATE` in my table called table1 which is a date in the format `CCYYMMDD` (This is a db2 database).

I want to retrieve `DUEDATE` records "within X days" of `ANYGIVENDATE`, so for example within 3 days of `ANYGIVENDATE` could mean all `DUEDATE` records that match dates 3 days before and after `ANYGIVENDATE`.

Although I can provide a `CCYYMMDD` argument I am struggling to compose the query.

I'm guessing I need to retrieve records

```
WHERE [DUEDATE] = [ANYGIVENDATE ± X DAYS]
```

(in `CCYYMMDD` format) ?

Comment: Which data type does the column `DUEDATE` have? Real dates don't have "a format".

Comment: Its called ZONED, I only came across it myself this week. Some kind of decimal.

Comment: Would I be correct in guessing that this is on an IBM i (aka iSeries or AS/400) server? Otherwise, is it a Linux/Unix/Windows type server, or a z/OS mainframe?

Comment: ...It often helps us give better answers for you, if we know the environment and release of your DB2 server.

Comment: Its on the iSeries, AS/400. I am using the JT400 toolbox for JDBC connectivity along with ibatis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored `DUEDATE` as the proper `DATE` data type, the query would simply be

```
...where DUEDATE between ANYGIVENDATE - X days and ANYGIVENDATE + X days
```

As it is, you could convert your values to the `DATE` data type, something like:

```
...where date(timestamp_format(varchar_format(DUEDATE),'YYYYMMDD')) 
         between date(timestamp_format(varchar_format(ANYGIVENDATE),'YYYYMMDD')) - X days
         and date(timestamp_format(varchar_format(ANYGIVENDATE),'YYYYMMDD')) + X days
```

which might hurt performance in some cases. On IBM System i (formerly known as AS/400) you might try

```
...where date(timestamp_format(varchar(DUEDATE),'YYYYMMDD')) 
         between date(timestamp_format(varchar(ANYGIVENDATE),'YYYYMMDD')) - X days
         and date(timestamp_format(varchar(ANYGIVENDATE),'YYYYMMDD')) + X days
```

because `VARCHAR_FORMAT()` there is only applicable to datetime data types. Alternatively you can calculate the boundary dates in the application and provide two decimal values in the `WHERE` clause:

```
...where DUEDATE between GIVENSTARTDATE and GIVENENDDATE
```

Comment: I can calculate the boundary date in the application so that should make things cleaner.

Comment: I tried: `"SELECT * FROM #BLUEWATER where date(timestamp_format(varchar_format(ADDUDT, 'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD'))  between date(timestamp_format('20141002','YYYYMMDD')) and date(timestamp_format('20141025','YYYYMMDD'))";` but got Argument 1 of function VARCHAR_FORMAT not valid

Comment: I guess if you make random changes to the suggested solution you will get random errors. What is the purpose of `varchar_format(ADDUDT, 'YYYYMMDD')`?

Comment: ADDUDT is the column actually containing the ZONED data type in the format YYYYMMDD.

Comment: There is a difference between `varchar_format(ADDUDT, 'YYYYMMDD')` and `varchar_format(ADDUDT)`-- the former is incorrect. Please check my suggestion again.

Comment: `varchar_format(ADDUDT)`  gave java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0170] Number of arguments for function VARCHAR_FORMAT not valid hence my tinkering. I tried `SELECT * FROM BLUEWATER where date(timestamp_format(varchar_format(ADDUDT),'YYYYMMDD'))  between date(timestamp_format('20141002','YYYYMMDD')) and date(timestamp_format('20141025','YYYYMMDD'))";`

Comment: See what happens when you don't specify your DB2 platform and version? Try `varchar(ADDUDT)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked ! Apologies, I still don't know what DB2 version. Its a remote AS400 system and I have limited access.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compare DATE to DATE, so the database column and the input parameter need to be converted.

Or better, you should pass a DATE parm value into the stored proc and eliminate conversion for that value.

Or pass it in as a DATE, subtract/add X DAYS to it, then convert those resulting date values to DECIMAL or NUMERIC and use them to compare against the database value. Given the improper definition of the database column, that's possibly the best choice.

It's not totally clear what `"within X days"` means.